# Swapping and changing out div content and replacing with other div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the click of one of the links on my side bar menu, how can I dynamically swap out existing `div` content with other its corresponding `div` and load it back into the `#content` div? I am jQuery friendly. Here is the HTML markup:

```css
#container {
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
}
#list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#list li {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    background: grey;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(192,192,192);
}
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #ff99CC;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: rgb(192,192,192);
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">        
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="list">
            <li>Coffee</li>
            <li>Tea</li>
            <li>Ice Cream</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="item1">Things about coffee...</div>
        <div id="item2">Things about tea...</div>    
        <div id="item3">Things about ice cream...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you've got nothing ?

Comment: You forgot to put your JavaScript code in the question. Where is the div content being loaded from?

Comment: the content is being loaded from the divs who's id's are item1/item2/item3, ie. if the user clicks on 'coffee', the dynamic content to be loaded is the div with the id# item1

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click http://api.jquery.com/index http://api.jquery.com/eq http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is indicative of the amount of content you have, then I wouldn't worry about "moving" things into the content div. I would just toggle the visibility of the various items, making only one visible at a time.

If the item divs have a class, like 'my-item' to help select them and a hidden class to hide them, ( `<div id="item1" class="hidden my-item">Something about coffee...</div>` )
And if the list items have a data attribute that selects the matching item: (`<li data-show="#item1">Coffee</li>`)

then this should work:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       //register this event handler on every li
       $("li").click(function(){ 
          var $li = $(this);
          var show_selector = $li.data("show");   // => "#item1"
          $(".my-item").addClass("hidden"); //hide all
          $(show_selector).removeClass("hidden"); //but show matching item
    });
});
```

Where   `.hidden{ display:none; }`

Comment: So this works, but if I click on a new LI then the items (divs) just keep getting stacked on top of each other, shouldnt't it hide the user's previous selection?

Comment: Did you put  class="my-item hidden" on each of the divs? Without that 'my-item' class they won't be selected by the  hide all step.

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden divs for the different content. `display: none;` initially and `$('.classofhidden').show();` / `$('.classofvisible').hide();`

```js
$('.content2').show();
```

```css
div[class^='content'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content1">1</div>
<div class="content2">2</div>
<div class="content3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("...").click(function(){
var div = $("#div1").html();
$("#div1").html($("#div2").html());
$("#div2").html(div);
});
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers are discouraged on SO.